# losing CCK custom field when saving

Tags: entities

I have installed varnish load balancer on my pressflow 6.22 website.
i have some custom fields created by CCK.
the original server is X and i have added another server Y to make this load balancer.
now, when the editors try to create any node when they were directed to server Y, they lost all custom fields when they save. however, when they are directed to  original server (X), everything goes fine with them!!
anyone faced such case? any idea about the reason or how can i fix it?
**** EDIT ****
i have checked in the DB and found that the image path has been saved normally, but when i make node_load, it didn't show this field. also when view or edit this node, the image is not shown as well!!
any idea is highly appreciated
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked content type -> manage fields -> display fields setting?
Also, do you have custom template for this node type, so that field won't show?

Comment: Check permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks 32i for your suggestion, i have managed my problem already.
it was a result of cache. when i flush all caches i get the content normally.
finally i found out the memcache is the caching level behind this problem, simply i excluded authenticated users from being served by memcache and this fixed my problem